# Snowflake operator (airflow) not rendering SQL properly

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a simple SQL Query using Airflow provider Snowflake (1.3.0)

```
 SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id=f'task',
        snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_conn',
        parameters={
            "table": "dummy_table",
        },
        sql=["delete from %(table)s"],
        autocommit=True,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

The SQL it is rendering is `delete from ''dummy''`. I want to get rid of `''` but have tried everything and nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 2):

To parametrize table name [IDENFITIER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) should be used:

> To use an object name specified in a literal or variable, use IDENTIFIER().

```
sql=["delete from IDENTIFIER(%(table)s)"],
```

The query `DELETE FROM 'dummy'` is not correct, but `DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER('dummy')` will work.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy(id INT);

DELETE FROM 'dummy';
-- Syntax error: unexpected ''dummy''. (line 4)

DELETE FROM IDENTIFIER('dummy');
-- number of rows deleted: 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about adding `identifier` but I want to know why the existing code not working. delete command was an example and there are more SQLs in that list and some might not support identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `parameters` then it's up to SQLAlchemy. You can find more information about it in [How to render a .sql file with parameters in MySqlOperator in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234432/how-to-render-a-sql-file-with-parameters-in-mysqloperator-in-airflow/72246305#72246305)

Alternatively, you can use Airflow rendering (Jinja engine) with `params`:

```
 SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id=f'task',
        snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_conn',
        params={
            "table": "dummy_table",
        },
        sql=["delete from {{ params.table }}"],
        autocommit=True,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

This will be rendered as:
[image]

thus the query that will be submitted to Snowflake is:

```
delete from dummy_table
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it actually parameter binding? I guess no. This is templating which Airflow provides so it is similar to python string formatting. I want to use best practices for SQL parameter binding to avoid situations like SQL injection. This will definitely work but might not be the best solution. What do you think?

Comment: @mad_ You wrote that you want to get rid of the `''` in the SQL statement.. So this was what I answered on. SQL injection is a risk but consider that if someone already hacked into your Airflow and has internal access then SQL injection is the least of your problem. Usually protection is added to prevent people from gaining access to Airflow, if someone gained access into your DAG folder then can do anything.

Comment: You can always also run additional step to verify the parameter you place before you actually place it. For example: compare the string (table name) to a list of known strings. I guess in snowflake it means to use `IDENTIFIER` so your SQL can be: `sql=["delete from IDENTIFIER('{{ params.table }}')"]`